# How to correctly secure Reverse Proxy communication with actual server in LAN

Tags: tls, openssl, apache-2.2, nginx

I have Nginx acting as gateway and reverse proxy for requests based on host name.

However, the communication with the actual server in lan isn't secured.

Does the connection remain encrypted with the following setup, or should I also secure Apache in the actual web server?

It must be noted that the LAN can not be totally trusted.

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.xxxx.edu.ar.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.xxxx.edu.ar.key;

        server_name
                tracker.yyyy.xxxx.edu.ar;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.yy.xx:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name
                tracker.yyy.xxxx.edu.ar;
        return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: As you say in your description, with this configuration SSL security will end at you Nginx proxy and the communication between the Nginx and Apache will be made in clear form. Where the SSL tunneling should end depends on your needs. You may find some inspiration [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/should-ssl-be-terminated-at-a-load-balancer), [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/reverse-proxy-secure-configuration) and [there](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58979/reverse-proxy-ssl).